# How do i create a mobile first responsive header

Tags: html, css, flexbox, media-queries, responsive

Please offer some advice and suggestions as to how to enable a mobile first responsive header. i cant seem to keep my content to the left when at mobile screen size also i need the header and back button to be the same size. Also when at a full screen size the header area doesn't spread. i use Flex-box but finding it difficult to align this particular content in the header. Any advise suggestions would be more than appreciated.

```css
.header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: #633;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}

.header a {
    float: left;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 25px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.header a.logo {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    justify-content: center;
}

.header a:hover {
    color: black;
}

.logo {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    transition: background 250ms ease-in-out, transform 150ms ease;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}

.home-button {
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: dodgerblue;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    transition: background 250ms ease-in-out, transform 150ms ease;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}

.header-right {
    float: right;
}

a.home-button:hover,
a.home-button:focus {
    background: #434344;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 300px) {
    .header,
    .header a,
    .home-button,
    .logo {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        float: none;
        display: block;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .header-right {
        float: none;
    }
}


/* end of header*/


/***********************************************
             **********************************************
             *********************************************/


/*   Back button CSS*/

.button {
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: dodgerblue;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    transition: background 250ms ease-in-out, transform 150ms ease;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}

.button:hover,
.button:focus {
    background: #434344;
}

.button:focus {
    outline: 1px solid #fff;
    outline-offset: -4px;
}

.button:active {
    transform: scale(0.99);
}
```

```html
 <div class="header">

        <div class="header-right">
            <a href="" class="logo"><img src="images/cw_logo.png" alt="company-logo"> </a>
            <a class="home-button" href="#home">Home</a>
            <a class="email" href="email@emailyou.com">email@emailyou.com</a>
            <a href="#about">
                <p>1234567890</p>
            </a>
            <button class="button" onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: when you say you want the home and back the same size, do you want them both wide (like the home when the snippet is run) or small (like the back button). A side note: header and button are native tags, you don't need to use them as classes (but you can give a button a class of back etc..)

Comment: Both small. Thanks for pointing that out. I've experimented with different methods and found it's to easy to overlook some basic concepts.